# Angular Formarray select drop-down issue

Tags: angular, forms, frontend, dropdown, formarray

when i change criteria (depends on selected criteria the data in the option select will change)
i can able to select option.but after adding more rows when i change one criteria it change all option select drop-down in all row's

**Here is the link of my problem in stack** :https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49722349-6pvgkh

**expected Behavior** :  when i select criteria only that row option need to change it will not effect other rows options.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49722349-iyq874) for working example.

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">

    <h1>Profile Form</h1>

    <div>
        <label for="first-name-input">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="first-name-input" formControlName="firstNameInput">
  </div>

  <div>
        <label for="last-name-input">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="last-name-input" formControlName="lastNameInput">
  </div>

    <div formArrayName="optionGroups">

        <div *ngFor="let $optionGroup of profileForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls;  let $index=index">

            <h4>Option {{ $index + 1 }} </h4>

            <div [formGroupName]="$index"> 
                <label for="select-input">Criteria</label>

                <select id="{{ 'select-input' + $index }}" formControlName="selectInput">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Criteria</option>
          <option *ngFor="let select of selects" [value]="select.name">{{select.id}}</option>
        </select>

                <label [for]="'where-input-' + $index">Option</label>
                <select [id]="'where-input-' + $index" formControlName="whereInput">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Option</option>
          <option *ngFor="let where of getWheresFor(profileForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls[$index].controls['selectInput'].value)" [value]="where.name">
            {{where.id}}
          </option>
        </select>

                <button type ="button" (click)="removeOptionGroup($index)">X</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

  <button type="button" (click)="addOptionGroup()">Add Options</button>

  <div>
        <button type="button" (click)="saveProfileForm()">Send</button>
  </div>

</form>

<pre>
{{ profileForm.value | json }}
</pre>
```

The important part is that once you select a "criteria" then the list of "Options" should be refreshed using this function:

```
  getWheresFor(inputStr: string): Where[] {
    return this.dropdownservice
      .getWhere()
      .filter(item => item.selectid === inputStr);
  }
```

called from your html like this:

```
getWheresFor(profileForm.controls['optionGroups'].controls[$index].controls['selectInput'].value)"
```

Also you can shorten the expression like this using the `$optionGroup` variable:

```
getWheresFor($optionGroup.controls['selectInput'].value)"
```

**UPDATE**

```
select [id]="'where-input-' + $index"
```

This will generate unique id's in the DOM for each `select` element. Typical use case is with `label` element which has a `for` attribute like this:

```
<label [for]="'select-input' + $index">Criteria</label>
<select id="{{ 'select-input' + $index }}" formControlName="selectInput">
```

This markup will generate dom elements like this:

[image]

The use of this is that now the user can click on the label's text and `select` element will get the focus.

Comment: <select [id]="'where-input-' + $index" 
could you please explain what is the use of this?